# How can I manipulate props and filters of List to fetch specific data?

Tags: list, react-admin

I want to have a `<List>` of related models in a `<TabbedShowLayout>` in `<Show>` of a model, so I can show related models in a `<Datagrid>` way and have `Actions` to create or delete related data. Similar to [reviews of posters in demo app](https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/products/2), but instead of just showing the related **Reviews**, I could create a **Review** for that **Poster**.

I was wondering if with a careful manipulation of `<List>` **props** and **filters** I could set it to fetch specific data? And if yes, how? I'm surfing the SourceCode of RA but I'm having trouble knowing how `<List>` fetches data, and what props are used for that fetch.

I know I could redirect user to a list of **Reviews** with **Poster** set as **filter**, but since I have other related models, not just Review, for better user experience I think that is better for user to have a `<TabbedShowLayout>` with tabs for related models, where a `<List>` just containing the related models is shown with `Actions` that can perform CRUD operations.

Comment: Are you aware of the `ReferenceManyField` component ? https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#referencemanyfield

Comment: You can see it in action on the demo: https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/customers/550

Comment: Yes, in fact I'm currently using it with a `Datagrid` however doesn't cover use cases where I want to show indirectly related data or many to many relations. For example taking the demo model where **Categories has many Product has many Reviews**; has many is a one to many relation. If in `Show` of Category I wanted to have a tab with Reviews associated with that Category I needed to have a nested `ReferenceManyField`, one for getting the Products and another inside of it to get Reviews, but column name would be of Products not Reviews. Nothing a label would not resolve but still not ideal.

Comment: And for many to many relations my backend should return an array of related models ids to use with `ReferenceArrayField` but that only resolves partially my problem since I want to performs action like Crate or Delete to add or remove related models and `ReferenceFields` seem to be purely presentational, with link to respective edit page.

Comment: I'm testing with v2.1.1 tab routing system I can adjust my backend to match the route in order to give related data to use in a `List`. I'm trying hard to use `List` instead of `ReferenceFields` because the first offers many utilities to create, manipulate and search data that the second seems not to possess.

Comment: Actually what a wanted is something like [this](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/1904), but since is not yet implemented there is any work around?

Answer (score 0):

The objective of this question was to know if something like this [RA enhancement](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/1904) existed and if not any work around possible.

**For now this answer is a record to know that feature is not yet implemented, when feature exists a proper solution will be given.**